# get the value of date picker used in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have create dynamic datepicker inside gridview. i want to know how to get the values of the datepicker

help me out!!

i have used this line

```
 DateTime date2 = DateTime.Parse(((TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("frmdate_endtime")).Text);
```

Comment: Why are you casting it to TextBox if it's a DateTimePicker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not cast the control to the appropriate date/time picker class and take the value from that directly? You shouldn't need to parse the text.